# parenthesis used in jsx render and curly inside jsx fuction

Tags: reactjs

In the code below why is the first instance of

`const classDropdownMenu = 'dropdown-menu' + (this.state.isToggleOn ?' show' : '')`

this.state.isToggleOn enclosed in paretheses, but the second instance

`{this.props.children}`

is enclosed in curly brackets.
I am new to reactjs and I am trying to grasp when to use curly brackets vs parentesis.

Is it because the first instance is using string concatenation in jsx and the second instance is evaluating a variable inside a jsx function?
So if you are inside a jsx function you need to evaluate, else jsx already knows about it?

```
class NavDropDown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
      isToggleOn:false
    }   
  }
  render(){
    const classDropdownMenu = 'dropdown-menu' + (this.state.isToggleOn ?' show' : '') 

    return (
      <li className="nav-item dropdown-toggle" hfref="/" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
      data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <div className={classDropDownMenu} aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
      </li>
    )   
  }
}
```

Comment: where's the second instance you're talking about? Do you mean `{this.props.children}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place,

```
const classDropdownMenu = 'dropdown-menu' + (this.state.isToggleOn ?' show' : '')
```

you are trying to execute an expression and add the result of this expression to `'dropdown-menu'` string and hence wrapped it within `()`. This is a Javascript syntax witing in a function.

For the second case

```
{this.props.children}
```

Where the content within `return ()` is a JSX content and expression in JSX are enclosed within `{}`.  For more details check the docs on [Embedding Expressions in JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx)

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Understood. Just use regular javascript unless I am inside react jsx calls. I am pretty sure the ( is just a line continuation In the return.